# Using XIB UIViewController with Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib, uitabbar

I have a storyboard where I keep my main tab bar controller, I am making some updates and want to add a tab of a view controller I already built with an XIB file. How can I use that View controller with my tab bar? Should I just copy and paste the view into my storyboard file?

Comment: If your new view controller is implemented in a xib then you cannot reference it from a storyboard. If I were you I would move your new view controller to its own storyboard and create a reference to it from the tab bar controller's storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can create a new scene in the storyboard and copy the view into the storyboard.  Having said that, if you use that XIB for other things you will then have two copies of the view to maintain, which is not ideal.

There are a few ways to address this.  Probably the simplest would be to transition places that use the XIB to load the view controller to load it from the storyboard instead and then remove the XIB entirely.

The other approach to consider would be to not add it to the storyboard and instead load the view controller from the XIB in a `viewDidLoad` implementation and insert it into the tab bar controller.  The most appropriate place for this would be either in a subclass of `UITabBarController` that you then set as the type of your storyboard tab bar scene or in a subclass of `UIViewController` that you setup as a container view controller in your storyboard with the tab bar controller embedded as a child view controller.  A `viewDidLoad` implementation in either place would probably be reasonable.